# Doesn't postman behave as a Browser?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postman

My REST API on Node allows a post in http://serverpath/login without the user session on cookies, what allows the login.

Doing a post on Postman, no auth, simple post with body:{"user:"user","password":"user"}, does the login, set the cookies on session and let me do any calls with no problems.

But when I try to the same on Browsers, I get not allow cors with wildcard (*).
I'm aware I can't use cors with credentials with wildcard. But why does it works in postman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postman is a Chrome extension, not a web page, so it has different limitations for cross origin requests.

See the Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest for Extensions on the Chrome Developer website:

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

"Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions."

Comment: I was hoping I was doing something wrong XD, and there was a way to do a cors with the wildcard, the same way Postman did, and work with credentials at the same time, so I could use the cookies on requests to keep up with server validations.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the postman isn't checking any security! If you disable the security in your browser (Chrome) then it also works!

shortly how to disable it in chrome: you have to launch your chrome.exe with these flags: `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

Comment: Tried that, but that would only solve during dev. But also didn't work XD.